# Rails3 Use of ActiveRecord ;scope failing with Time#succ is obsolete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I'm banging my head against the wall - am using various scopes within ActiveRecord some work and some don't and I can't figure out why.  Would love to have someone give me a hint/solution.  All scope statements are within the same Model - PortfolioProject.  All are called with the following:

```
PortfolioProject.<scope name>(Time.zone.now).order('sequence')
```

This one works - every time without fail:

```
scope :in_discovery, lambda {|curTime| where('sequence > 0 AND ? BETWEEN crnt_discovery_start AND crnt_discovery_finish', curTime) }
```

The following fail and gives the error message: **Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1**

```
scope :in_requirements, lambda {|curTime|  where('sequence > 0 AND ? BETWEEN crnt_requirements_start AND crnt_requirements_finish', curTime) }
scope :in_tech_design, lambda {|curTime|  where('sequence > 0 AND ? BETWEEN crnt_tech_dsgn_start AND crnt_tech_dsgn_finish', curTime) }
scope :in_development, lambda {|curTime|  where('sequence > 0 AND ? BETWEEN crnt_development_start AND crnt_development_finish', curTime) }
scope :in_testing, lambda {|curTime|  where('sequence > 0 AND ? BETWEEN crnt_testing_start AND crnt_testing_finish', curTime) }
scope :in_launch, lambda {|curTime|  where('sequence > 0 AND ? BETWEEN crnt_launch_start AND crnt_launch_finish', curTime) }
```

The construction of the scope statements are identical - except for the column names used within each statement.

I appreciate any insight in to what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Folks - the issue was further down the stack in the program - I was chasing a ghost as Rails wasn't reporting any trace information with the error and I assumed it was in the scope statement.  Just as any FYI - my final scope statement is as follows:

```
scope :in_discovery, lambda{|dtCheck| active_records.where('DATE(?) BETWEEN crnt_discovery_start AND crnt_discovery_finish', dtCheck)}
```

Works like a champ.

The problem ended up being in a sub view where I again was doing a comparison of fields that are of datatyep TIMESTAMP in the DB2 database.  Since it is a legacy app where I can't change datatypes, all I had to do in the view is add the '.to_date' at the end of the field declaration.